# Craft Commerce Stripe

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-commerce-stripe

I am using the commerce-stripe plugin and its all working ok. I was thinking about having a quick checkout option for products (so users dont have to go through basket and checkout etc).

Is there a way to override the total price in the basket with the product price somehow?

I tried this:

```
{% set params = {
    total: {
        label: 'Demo total',
        amount: 1099, 
    },      
                                                  
    paymentFormType: 'checkout',                              
    submitButtonText: 'Make Payment ,
} %}
```

It creates a nice simple button but always uses the basket total. Any ideas? Or a different appraoch?